# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '` but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, razor

Here i am consuming a WCf service in MVC and retrieving values from that service and trying to show it in a view.getting the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List` but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

**Service Code:**

```
public IList<AddressDetails> GetAddressDetails(string addressid)
        {
            List<AddressDetails> addressdetails = new List<AddressDetails>();
             {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name,EmailAddress,Line1,City from Address where addressid ='6742596A-F413-4C71-8BAB-0016F96B56A0'", con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        AddressDetails addressInfo = new AddressDetails();
                        //addressInfo.Addressid = dt.Rows[i]["Addressid"].ToString();
                        addressInfo.Name = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                        addressInfo.EmailAddress = dt.Rows[i]["EmailAddress"].ToString();
                        addressInfo.Line1 = dt.Rows[i]["Line1"].ToString();
                        addressInfo.City = dt.Rows[i]["City"].ToString();
                        addressdetails.Add(addressInfo);
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            return addressdetails;
        }
```

**Controller Code:**

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client objService = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        public ActionResult sample()
        {
            IList<AddressDetails> objAddressDetails = new List<AddressDetails>();
            objAddressDetails = objService.GetAddressDetails("");
            return View(objAddressDetails.ToList());
        }
```

**View Code:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Magelia.WebStore.StarterSite.Web.Models.Sample.SampleViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "sample";
}

<h2>sample</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            AddressId
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            EmailAddress
        </th>
        <th>
            Line1
        </th>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddressId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Line1)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You've got  IList<AddressDetails> in your controller, but some IEnumerable<Magelia.WebStore.StarterSite.Web.Models.Sample.SampleViewModel> in a view...probable the problem is that `AddressDetails` cannot be cast to `...SampleViewModel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is in the bit you missed out for the question - the expected *element type* of the sequence in the view, and the *element type* of the list.

Here's what you're creating in the model:

```
IList<AddressDetails> objAddressDetails = new List<AddressDetails>();
```

But here's what the model declares it needs:

```
@model IEnumerable<Magelia.WebStore.StarterSite.Web.Models.Sample.SampleViewModel>
```

You should have

```
@model IEnumerable<AddressDetails>
```

My guess is that you copied and pasted the model declaration without looking - always make sure you understand every line of what you copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following line of code (in controller):

```
return View(objAddressDetails.AsEnumerable());
```

Comment: I don't believe that's the problem. See my answer for what I suspect is really wrong. `IList<T>` already extends `IEnumerable<T>`.